# Wordpress: Current menu item only highlights when inspector is open

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink

The site I am working on: http://www.GreenvilleOsaka.com/

I am trying to highlight the current page the user is on, but my rule as seen below only seems to disable highlight color causing the link to retain its normal color:

```
.current-menu-item a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Oddly enough, when I inspect it with Google Chrome, it changes to the hover color (grey) but  the inspector matched CSS rules shows white (the correct color), and even weirder, the computed styles shows the original link color (gold).

If I open inspector some other way then walk to the current menu item, it stays the wrong color (normal, gold) but the inspector shows the correct color (white) in both computed and matched CSS rules.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

(Inspecting in FF with FireBug shows correct colors while the  is gold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css from

```
.current-menu-item a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

to

```
.current-menu-item a {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Comment: Lol, I just had one of those moments on a file upload script.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as answered? (assuming it worked.)